# Non-blocking (lock-free) one-time initialization

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, lock-free

### Original question:

I need to initialize something only once in a multi-threaded application (when first thread enters the block). Subsequent threads should skip the initialization without waiting for it to complete.

I've found this blog entry [Lock-free Thread Safe Initialisation in C#](http://kozmic.net/2011/01/05/lock-free-thread-safe-initialisation-in-c/) but it does not do exactly what I want, as it makes the other threads wait for the initialization to complete (if I understand it correctly).

Here's an example that presents the issue, although it does not work due to lack of synchronization:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace LockFreeInitialization
{
    public class Program
    {
        private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> _jobsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();
        private volatile bool _initialized;

        private async Task EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync(int taskId, int jobId)
        {
            Enqueue(taskId, jobId);

            /* "Critical section"? Only the first thread to arrive should
             * execute OneTimeInitAsync. Subsequent threads should always
             * skip this part. This is where things go wrong as all the
             * tasks execute this section due to lack of synchronization. */
            if (!_initialized)
            {
                await OneTimeInitAsync(taskId);
            }

            /* Before and during initialization, all threads should skip
             * the ProcessQueueAsync. After initialization is completed,
             * it does not matter which thread will execute it (since the
             * _jobsQueue is thread-safe). */
            if (_initialized)
            {
                await ProcessQueueAsync(taskId);
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} completed.");
        }

        private void Enqueue(int taskId, int jobId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} enqueues job {jobId}.");
            _jobsQueue.Enqueue(jobId);
        }

        private async Task OneTimeInitAsync(int taskId)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} is performing initialization");

            /* Do some lengthy initialization */
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            _initialized = true;

            Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} completed initialization");
        }

        private async Task ProcessQueueAsync(int taskId)
        {
            while (_jobsQueue.TryDequeue(out int jobId))
            {
                /* Do something lengthy with the jobId */
                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

                Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} completed job {jobId}.");
            }
        }

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            var rand = new Random();

            /* Start 4 tasks in parallel */
            for (var threadId = 1; threadId < 5; threadId++)
            {
                p.EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync(threadId, rand.Next(10));
            }

            /* Give tasks chance to finish */
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Both `OneTimeInitAsync` and `ProcessQueueAsync` are lengthy operations that in real-life scenario would communicate with some remote services. Using `lock` would block the other threads, while I want them to just pile up their work onto `_jobsQueue` and go their way. I tried using `ManualResetEvent` to no avail.

Does anyone know how would I make this work? Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATE (solution)

Based on the discussion below I understood that the scenario presented was not complete to describe my problem. However thanks to the answers and comments I thought about redesigning the solution a bit, to work as I wanted it to.

So imagine two remote services **ServiceA** (*job processor*) and **ServiceB** (*job repository*) that the client app has to communicate with. We need to establish a connection to ServiceA, meanwhile we get data for multiple jobs from ServiceB. As the jobs data become available, we process jobs (in batches) using ServiceA (real-life example involves Signal-R connection to ServiceA and some job IDs from ServiceB that need to be sent to ServiceA). Here's the code example:

```
public class StackOverflowSolution
{
    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<int> _jobsQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

    /* Just to randomize waiting times */
    private readonly Random _random = new Random();

    /* Instance-scoped one-time initialization of a remote ServiceA connection */
    private async Task<string> InitializeConnectionAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(InitializeConnectionAsync)} started");

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_random.Next(5) + 1));

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(InitializeConnectionAsync)} completed");

        return "Connection";
    }

    /* Preparation of a job (assume it requires communication with remote ServiceB) */
    private async Task InitializeJobAsync(int id)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(InitializeJobAsync)}({id}) started");

        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_random.Next(10) + 1));
        _jobsQueue.Enqueue(id);

        Console.WriteLine($"{nameof(InitializeJobAsync)}({id}) completed");
    }

    /* Does something to the ready jobs in the _jobsQueue using connection to
     * ServiceA */
    private async Task ProcessQueueAsync(string connection)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder("Processed ");
        bool any = false;
        while (_jobsQueue.TryDequeue(out int idResult))
        {
            any = true;
            sb.Append($"{idResult}, ");
        }
        if (any)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_random.Next(500)));
            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        }
    }

    /* Orchestrates the processing */
    public async Task RunAsync()
    {
        /* Start initializing the conection to ServiceA */
        Task<string> connectionTask = InitializeConnectionAsync();
        /* Start initializing jobs */
        var jobTasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (int id in new[] {1, 2, 3, 4})
        {
            jobTasks.Add(InitializeJobAsync(id));
        }
        /* Wait for initialization to complete */
        string connection = await connectionTask;

        /* Trigger processing of jobs as they become ready */
        var queueProcessingTasks = new List<Task>();
        while (jobTasks.Any())
        {
            jobTasks.Remove(await Task.WhenAny(jobTasks));
            queueProcessingTasks.Add(ProcessQueueAsync(connection));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(queueProcessingTasks);
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        new StackOverflowSolution().RunAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

Output example:

```
InitializeConnectionAsync started
InitializeJobAsync(1) started
InitializeJobAsync(2) started
InitializeJobAsync(3) started
InitializeJobAsync(4) started
InitializeJobAsync(5) started
InitializeJobAsync(3) completed
InitializeJobAsync(2) completed
InitializeConnectionAsync completed
Processed 3, 2,
InitializeJobAsync(1) completed
Processed 1,
InitializeJobAsync(5) completed
Processed 5,
InitializeJobAsync(4) completed
Processed 4,
```

Thanks for all the feedback!

Comment: Is `Lazy<T>` not an option?

Comment: Could you give an example on how would I use it in this case?

Comment: You seem to want the "first worker" to do the initialization.  Couldn't you just DO the initialization, THEN launch the workers?  Your example may be TOO synthetic to make sense for what you're really trying to do.

Comment: @KevinAnderson initialization establishes connection to a remote service. Creating a job requires communicating with another service, and then processing it requires the first connection to be initialized. I'd like to start creating the jobs while i initialize the connection.

Comment: Honestly the design is rather problematic to begin with.  You shouldn't be doing a busywait while waiting for work to do.

Comment: Does `OneTimeInitAsync` actually need to know the taskID?  Why is the initialization dependant on the task?

Comment: @Servy That very well might be so. Can you suggest an idea how to redesign this? As noted in the comment for Kevin I want to start communicating with service B (to create jobs) while I communicate with service A (to create the connection) to then process the jobs with service A.

Comment: @Servy no it does not need to know it. It's just to display the trace more or less.

Comment: Could you create a `Lazy<Task>` that represents the initialization and then use `ContinueWith` in place of the explicit queue?

Comment: @Caleb9 If you don't need it, then do pass it through, that greatly complicates the task.  Also, why do you want to just drop requests on the floor if they're made while someone else is busy initializing the class?  Why *shouldn't* they just wait (asynchronously) for the initialization to finish and then proceed to actually do the work for that task?

Comment: Caleb, it is then appropriate IMO for the workers to wait on the connections.  So you have a mixed job queue with "sets" of workers, with each set associated with a connection.  The init problem isn't your "biggest" one IMO, it's what happens when a connection has an error.  It's a design problem, and one you'll have to deal with.  And what @Servy said too about needing the workers to wait for init.  They pretty much have to IMO.

Comment: @Caleb9 It also doesn't make sense for the processing to always process *all* of the items in the queue.  Between that and sometimes not processing items at all you make the `Task` returned from `EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync` useless.  Really it should complete when the enqueued item is processed, not when the queue is next empty, which could have resulted in any number of items being processed.

Comment: True, I should think this through once again. Maybe I'm pushing myself in a wrong corner...

Comment: Currently you process items in parallel, after initialization.  Is that desired, or do you want to limit it to only processing one item at a time?

Comment: @Servy They should be processed in parallel, however it does not matter if several of them will be processed by a single thread. Imagine collecting some sort of IDs that get sent in bulks through the connection that needs to be initialized.

Comment: @Caleb9 If that's what you want, that's fine, it just seems odd.  since you have a connection here, I'd expect it's not designed to support multiple parallel requests, and probably only works when asked to perform one request at a time.  If that's not the case, then that's fine, just...unexpected.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792409(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Honestly the semantics of `EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync` for your code is simply not a good idea, given your description of what you're actually doing and what you actually need.

Currently the `Task` returned from `EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync` waits for initialization *if initialization wasn't started by someone else*, then it completes whenever the queue is empty, or as soon as this logical call context happened to process an item that errored.  That...just doesn't make sense.

What you clearly want is for that `Task` to be completed whenever the job passed in completed (which will of course require initialization to complete), or to be errored if that job errors, and to be unaffected by any other job's errors.  Fortunately in addition to being much more useful, it's also *far* easier to do.

As far as the actual initialization goes, you can just use a `Lazy<Task>` to ensure proper synchronization of the asynchronous initialization, and to expose the `Task` to any future calls which can tell them when initialization has finished.

```
public class MyAsyncQueueRequireingInitialization
{
    private readonly Lazy<Task> whenInitialized;
    public MyAsyncQueueRequireingInitialization()
    {
        whenInitialized = new Lazy<Task>(OneTimeInitAsync);
    }
    //as noted in comments, the taskID isn't actually needed for initialization
    private async Task OneTimeInitAsync() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Performing initialization");

        /* Do some lengthy initialization */
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));

        Console.WriteLine($"Completed initialization");
    }

    public async Task ProcessJobAsync(int taskID, int jobId)
    {
        await whenInitialized.Value;

        /* Do something lengthy with the jobId */
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

        Console.WriteLine($"Completed job {jobId}.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Ok I guess I did not specify that in the question, but with this solution each `jobId` is processed by one task. So accumulating and then processing let's say 4 jobIds by one task, and then another 3 by another does not work. That's why I tried to use the queue. Basically I'd like to accumulate IDs while initialization is executing, and then bulk-process them (e.g. send several IDs in one request to a remote service). Not sure if it makes sense, I need to digest all of this information now ;).

Comment: @Caleb9 Yes, I specifically explained why I made that change in the answer.  It's a *desirable* change.  You don't get anything out of doing it your way, other than making the `Task` returned by `EnqueueAndProcessJobsAsync` meaningless to any caller.  My code makes that `Task` return a useful result, and otherwise behaves the same.

Comment: @Caleb9 Even if your code you're still processing the items one at a time.  If you want to group items together and send them in batches, then by what criteria do you want to batch them?  Sure you can batch up all of the requests that come in during initialization, but what then?  Once initialized, when do you want to queue items up for a later batch and when should the batches actually go out?

Comment: thanks for all the feedback. Basically the real-life scenario is collecting bunch of IDs and then "registering" them with Signal-R service that will start propagating events for each of the IDs independently from others. So initialization is creating a Signal-R connection, then registering IDs should happen in batches (service supports that) to limit the number of requests. Meanwhile the initialization is executing, new IDs might become available and should also be registered after. Anyway I need to do some coding to understand if your solution might be sufficient here. I'll be back ;)

Comment: @Caleb9 That didn't actually answer any of my questions.  By what criteria are you batching items?  How do you determine when a batch should be sent out, vs waiting for more items to go in the request?  Currently you're batching items that come in during initial initialization, but after that you're *basically* never batching any items ever (there are race conditions where it's theoretically possible, but it's highly unlikely to actually happen).

Comment: yes, in this scenario the list of job IDs will very rarely or not at all be modified. The thing is that after obtaining the IDs I have to process them locally (and this will vary in length depending on other factors, i.e. how much work there is to do for each ID) before registering them in the service. So if connection initialization takes 5 seconds, and I have few IDs already processed locally (each took less than 5 seconds), I'd like to register them in one go. Afterwards, those that took more than 5 seconds can be registered one at a time as their processing completes.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments to the OP, a better solution might be to do the initialization in single-threaded mode, and then launch the threads that do the actual work.

If that doesn't work for you, you'll need a lock of some sort - but you can use that lock just for scheduling, to make it less blocking. I would implement something like this:

```
private bool _initializationIsScheduled = false;
private object _initializationIsScheduledLock = new object();
private bool _isInitialized = false;
private object _isInitializedLock = new object();

private async Task EnqueueAndProcessJobs(int taskId, int jobId)
{
    var shouldDoHeavyWork = false;

    lock(_initializationIsScheduledLock)
    {
        if (!_initializationIsScheduled)
        {
            shouldDoHeavyWork = true;
            _initializationIsScheduled= true;
        }
    }

    if (shouldDoHeavyWork)
    {
        await OneTimeInitAsync(taskId);
        lock (_isInitializedLock)
        {
            _isInitialized = true;
        }
    }

    lock (_isInitializedLock)
    {
        if (_isInitialized)
        {
            shouldDoHeavyWork = true;
        }
    }

    if (shouldDoHeavyWork)
    {
        await ProcessQueueAsync(taskId);
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"Task {taskId} completed.");
}
```

Note how the only time the thread locks up the other threads, is when it's about to check or set one of the flags that controls its work. In other words, threads don't have to wait for each other when actually doing heavy work, just when scheduling it (i.e. for a couple of CPU cycles when setting the boolean flags).

The code isn't exactly beautiful, but you should be able to refactor the above sample into something that's reasonably legible... :)

Comment: you cannot `lock` on a boolean.

Comment: @Servy: Heh, that's what happens when you throw together code samples directly on SO without testing them locally first. However, the principle is the same - just introduce two `object` instances to lock on instead.

Comment: Thanks @TomasLycken I'll give this a try.

Comment: Double-checked locking is fine for some things, but you should just lock and then check if init is done.  It's CHEAP to lock: http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking

Comment: @KevinAnderson Fair point. I've edited and removed the DCL, since it mostly added complexity to the code sample anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
static bool IsInitializing = false;
static int FirstThreadId = -1;

// check if initialised
// return if initialised

// somewhere in init mehtod
lock (lockObject)
{
   // first method start initializing
   IsInitializing = true;

   // set some id to the thread that start initializtion
   FirstThreadId = THIS_THREAD_OR_TASK_ID;
}

if (IsInitializing && FristThread != THIS_THREAD_OR_TASK_ID)
   return; // skip initializing
```

`lock` must work quick, yeap

Comment: Static won't cut it - I need to be able to have several separate instances of this class (they don't share the jobs or connections, but each might be processed from several threads).

Comment: @Caleb9 but this static fields used only inside lock(...)
Of course you can separate instances of this class, there is no problem, changing this static fields is protected by lock(...). 
If you want to "initialize something only once in a multi-threaded application" it will work nice, simplest way i think. Only cost is waiting while bool field set. 

UP: and you of course need to check if resource is initialised before lock